# What is the song played during Sasuke's and Itachi's final battle?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the Naruto Shippuden song played during Sasuke's and Itachi's final battle (episode 135 of Naruto Shippuden)? The song starts playing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjfA-JetlHw&t=2m25s).

Comment: Just a bit of info, if you want to view a Youtube video starting at a certain point, you can add &t=(number of minutes)m(numberofseconds)s at the end of the link. It would be extremely convenient for you and for all of us.

Comment: By the way, do you know which episode or season is this from? I'm trying to use brute force as I, myself, am not too familiar with the series.

Answer (score 2):

Bingo. The name of this song is ***Hidan***. You can check it out [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5FjkQQql4I).

Though it might sound a bit higher in pitch to the link you provided, the tune seems very pretty much alike, maybe it was modified because of, you know, to avoid copyright infringement.